# Check if OrientDB is in backup mode/

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

We need to check in client app if OrientDB is creating backup. 
Is there any way to check?

Answer (score 0):

OrientDB supports backup and and restore operations, like any database management system.
The Backup can be performed by running the `BACKUP DATABASE` command. It's possible to automatize backups using the Automatic Backup server plugin, by modifying the

```
orientdb-server-config.xml
```

you should see the scheduled time in the server, like this one:

[image]

If you didn't modified the correct parameter in this file, you shouldn't have automatic backup enabled.

In case if you're using the Enterprise Edition you can check backup settings in the Server Management Area.

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Michela Bonizzi. The problem is that during backup our guaranteed SOAP message delivery system (24/7) is not working properly. SOAP request got cut during backup by timeout, but thread is still working and waiting to create objects in DB. As the result the second, third and so on requests (the same SOAP because of gurantee) fail or create duplicate data, which is not so good. That's why i need programmatically find out when orient is in backup mode.